# 2 VPC Network connections to MongoDB Atlas for 2 different GCP Projects

Tags: mongodb, airflow, mongodb-atlas

We are trying to setup 2 VPC peering connections to mongodb atlas
Each from a different GCP project.
We are getting the following error when trying to setup the VPC network peering in GCP when trying to setup the 2nd one (the 1st connection works).

> Operation type [addPeering] failed with message "An IP range in the
> local network (XX.XXX.0.0/X0) allocated by resource
> (projects/XXXXX/regions/XXXX/subnetworks/default) overlaps with an IP
> range (XX.XXX.0.0/X0) in an active peer of the peer network."

Any assistance would be appreciated